# Why am I getting an error "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST." when I am actually making a post request?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, http, axios

I am working in a Vue app with a Laravel api and I am getting exactly what it says in the title.

My Axios call: `return await axios.post("/customers/load-cart-data", payload);`

Inside the general section of my network tab: `Request Method: POST`

What I get back from our api: `"message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."`

I even log out the `req` in an interceptor and it says: `....,method: "post"`

I am just wondering if there is some server routes configuration something that is missing or if there is anything I can do to fix this.

Thank you all!

Comment: This is a question about your API, not about the way you are accessing it. You don't give us any information about the API you are using or what is behind it, so how could we know why it would give an inappropriate error message and/or reject a perfectly valid request?

Comment: in your `web.php` or `api.php` change route from `get` to `post`

Comment: Share your routes, we cannot help you if you don't fully show your `api.php` and `web.php`...

Comment: My guess is that you have a redirect somewhere. If you POST to a url that does a 301/302 redirect, the redirect method will be a GET (without the post data). This could be a redirect setup in your application, or it could be a web server HTTP -> HTTPS redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happens when you declare the same name of route for api.php and web.php with different method, for a api.php you should use post method and web.php should be routes for pages.

After change the route names on your api on the console write this command.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

with this you should clear all routes cache and after this try test your api.

Comment: The error message is not indicative of a bad route definition. The message tells us they've defined a POST route, but they are hitting it with a GET request. OP claims they're making a POST request, but the application is receiving a GET request, hence the message saying "GET is invalid; use POST" (paraphrased).

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you mixing up your http and https or if you use the wrong domain extension.

This problem happened to me recently where I was using `.com` instead of `.net`

To confirm this is happening to you, inspect your network requests (if you have F12 web dev tools, then use the Network tab), then you will see that your POST request was returned with a 301. Then, this would be followed by a GET request to the same URL.